# How to open and edit TFS reports?

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, tfs-reports

I would like to change some of the reports defined in my TFS project. I have tried going to the report administration page, select the properties of the report I want to edit download its .rdl file through the "Edit" option.

After that, I created a reporting services solution and added the .rdl to this solution. It opens correctly but the problem is that he doesn't know the shared data source and I cannot find a way to add them to the solution.

Is there a way to download the published data source and add it to the project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, Gimly, what's happening? Aahh, now, are you going to go ahead and have those TFS reports for us this afternoon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [TFS Guide](http://tfsguide.codeplex.com/). In Part VII there is a section on how to modify the reports.